# How do I disable the "Check your passwords" prompt in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Everytime I log into anything on my local network (where I use passwords like "password" on development web hosts) I get a warning from Chrome that I have to manually hit "close" on. When I'm frequently spinning up and shutting down web servers this becomes tedious. I'm sure the feature is useful to others but the annoyance it's causing me makes it more trouble than it's worth. How can I turn this feature off?

[image]

Answer (score 22):

To disable this:
Go  to setting -> Click on "Privacy and setting" -> open "Security" -> Turn off the "Enhanced protection" and switch to "Standard protection".

Just make sure the "Warn you if passwords are exposed in a data breach" is disabled (Which is disabled by default)

Comment: Sadly, disabling such warning is not exactly what the OP wants to do. Even if it does disable the warning, it also makes Chrome not to warn you about data breaches on other sites where one uses strong passwords and such warning would actually be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This feature was optional in the past and was called
"Warn you if passwords are exposed in a data breach".
However, it's no longer optional.
It will "protect" you against using very common passwords, whether you want it
or not.

To get rid of it,
the best solution is to mangle the passwords a bit.
Otherwise, the solution would be to use another browser that doesn't do this check.

Comment: A third option, get all the passwords stored in Chrome out of there (delete) and use a third party password manager in its place, such as LastPass. This is easiest accomplished by first installing the browser plugin and having it working, then login to each site and use chrome to fill in the password. LastPass should detect it and asks if you want to store it. Do so, then remove from chrome.

Comment: @LPChip I don't think that would help. In this case I'm not saving the password. Chrome is just telling me that the password I just typed in is "unsafe".

Comment: @quant it does so, because you stored those passwords in chrome. It can't do it unless you once told Chrome to store the password.

Comment: @LPChip nope, the password isn't stored.

Comment: It's optional again.  You could update your answer to reflect this.